# How to put values from a look_down tree array's HTML tag into a regular array in Perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, html-tree

This is a snippet of code I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Time::Piece;
use HTML::Tree;

my $url0 = 'http://www.website.ch/blah.aspx';

my $doc0 = get($url0);

my $tree0 = HTML::Tree->new();
$tree0->parse($doc0);

my @juice = $tree0->look_down(
    _tag => 'option'
);

foreach ( @juice )
{
    print $_->as_HTML, "\n";
}
```

I understand that there are easier ways to do this--feel free to talk about those ways, but I'm doing it this way for now. I would like to put all the `value` entries into an array, so *e.g.* if one of my (what I'm calling) look_down tree array elements is the following

`<option value="YIDDSH">Yiddish</option>`,

then I would like to somehow push "YIDDSH" (without quotes) into an array, and the pull in the next value from the next element in the array.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the `attr` method to extract the contents of the `value` attribute, and the [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) function to loop over all the elements.

```
my @values = map { $_->attr('value') } @juice;
```

Comment: Can you match and replace in the same line? That is, what if I have `value="PIG&PORK S"`, and I want to replace every instance of `&` with `#` and every instance of ` ` with `0`.

Comment: `map { my $s = $_->attr('value'); $s =~ s/&/#/g; $s =~ s/ /0/g; $s }`

Comment: `map { $_->attr('value') =~ s/&/#/rg =~ s/ /0/rg }` (requires 5.14+)